# CouchBase Lite - update document - Android, why is "properties.putAll(..)" needed?

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

[Here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html#updating-documents) it is described how to update a document in Couchbase Lite.

I noticed that if I uncomment `properties.putAll(doc.getProperties());` in the code below then the update does not take place, **why** ?

```
Document doc = database.getDocument(myDocID);
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.putAll(doc.getProperties()); // IF I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE, THE UPDATE DOES NOT WORK, WHY ?
properties.put("title", title);
properties.put("notes", notes);
try {
    doc.putProperties(properties);
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My guess is that it is because of some hidden property, not sure though.

EDIT:

Here is another example code that shows this issue:

```
   static public void storeDoc(Database db, String key, Map<String, Object> p){
        // Save the document to the database
        Document document = db.getDocument(key);
        Map<String, Object> p1 = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, Object> oldprops=document.getProperties();
        if (oldprops!=null) p1.putAll(oldprops); //if I uncomment this line then the update does not work

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object > e:p.entrySet()) {
            p1.put(e.getKey(),e.getValue());
        }

        try {
            document.putProperties(p1);
        } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, first answer was using wrong code.  Which version of CBL are you using?  This works for me in 1.2.1.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  Is there an exception?  The data is simply not updated?

Comment: Yeah. Not updated.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve a document, you get a copy which contains an immutable version of the data.  You can deal with this by copying the map into a separate map object, then overwriting the old map.

In case you don't want to use putAll alternatively, you can use createRevision() to obtain a new UnsavedRevision. This returns a copy of the latest revision, but with mutable contents. You can then manipulate the properties map directly. Changes are committed by calling save().

```
UnsavedRevision update = document.createRevision();
profile = update.getProperties();
profile.put("type", "profile");  // Add a "type" to the document

try {
  update.save();
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException ex) {
  Log.e(TAG, "CBL operation failed");
}
```